# Mercurial .hgignore exlude all files not '.txt' in all subfolders of specified folder

Tags: mercurial, hgignore

having directory structure

```
foo
 -1.txt
 -1.notxt
 -bar
  -2.txt
  -3.notxt
  -sub
   -1.txt
   -2.txt
another-folders-and-files
```

Want to exclude all non-'.txt' files in folder *foo* and its subfolders.
The most similar is this pattern:

```
^foo/(?!.*\.txt$)
```

But it exclude not only *1.notxt* file from *foo*, but all subfolders too.
I think, it because of *bar* is matches my exclusion pattern, but I do not understand how to say to hg not to ignore *bar*.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you have no directory names with (non-initial) periods in them, you can leverage that.

Comment: @alexis, sorry I don't understand your post. My English is not good. What do periods in directory names mean?

Comment: I meant that any name that contains a non-initial period is a file, not a directory (in many set-ups, hopefully in yours). So, you could write a regexp that excludes everything containing a dot and not ending in .txt.

Comment: (period = dot; directory = folder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately mercurial ignore patterns don't distinguish between files and directories; so if you ignore *every* name that doesn't end in `.txt`, you'll ignore directories too. But since directory names don't usually have a suffix, what you *can* do is ignore every name that has a suffix other than `.txt`, like this:

```
^foo/.*[^/]\.[^/]*$(?<!txt)
```

Breakdown:

`^foo/.*` any path in foo/; followed by

`[^/]\.` a period preceded by (at least) one non-slash character; followed by

`[^/]*$`, a path-final suffix; finally:

`(?<!txt)` check that there was no `txt` immediately before the end of the line.

This lets through names that begin with a period (`.hgignore`), and names containing no period at all (`README`). If you have files with no suffix you'll have to find another way to exclude them, but this should get you most of the way there. If you have directory names with dots in the middle, this will suppress them and you'll need to work harder to exclude them-- or change your approach.

(Incidentally, it's probably safer to have a long list of ignored suffixes, and add to it as necessary; soon enough the list will stabilize, and you won't risk ignoring something that shouldn't be.)

Comment: Thank you for full answer. I understand, that better I must exclude all trash folders and add necessary files to repository manually. I made a mistake, when thinked that a regexp can describe all my thoughts). If mercurial could apply a regexp to full path string, it could be better.

Comment: Mercurial *does* apply a regexp to a full path string, when you "anchor" it with `^` and `$` (as you did already); your problem was that the regexp is also applied to the full path of the _directories_ in the repository, and then it never looks inside.